# Using OTG cables with Nexus 7 (2012) without rooting

Tags: nexus-7, usb-on-the-go

Is it possible to use OTG Cables with Nexus 7 (2012) without rooting? Can Nexus Media Importer be useful here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Nexus Media Importer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.homeysoft.nexususb.importer).

From its description:

> This is the only non-root solution for devices that do not provide
>   native support for external storage.

**Other references:**

- [Usb otg without root access for nexus 7 found!](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1844567)